# Shell script to execute commands in remote and then exit shell to perform next operation in local

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm writing a shell script to perform a series of actions in remote. Then I want to come back to local and perform the next series of actions. When I use exit, I'm exiting from the shell script instead of logging out of the remote machine.

```
set -x

ssh $1

cd /var/log/sysstat/

for (( i = 11; i <= 19; i++ ))

do

 sar -f $i >> /home/sirish.aditya/cpu_11-19.csv

 sar -f $i -r >> /home/sirish.aditya/mem_11-19.csv

done

exit 

mkdir /Users/sirish.aditya/workSpace/cpustats_srm/$1

scp sirish.aditya@$1:/home/sirish.aditya/mem_11-19.csv /Users/sirish.aditya/workSpace/cpustats_srm/$1

scp sirish.aditya@$1:/home/sirish.aditya/cpu_11-19.csv /Users/sirish.aditya/workSpace/cpustats_srm/$1
```

--

```
ssh sirish.aditya@remote_machine 'bash -s' < memory.sh remote_machine
```

Can somebody help on this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the part of the remote execution to external script and then conditional piping it to `exit` function.

For example:

`exec_in_remote.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /var/log/sysstat/    
for (( i = 11; i <= 19; i++ ))
do
 sar -f $i >> /home/sirish.aditya/cpu_11-19.csv
 sar -f $i -r >> /home/sirish.aditya/mem_11-19.csv
done
```

And then in your main script:

```
set -x
ssh $1 'bash -s' < exec_in_remote.sh

mkdir /Users/sirish.aditya/workSpace/cpustats_srm/$1
scp sirish.aditya@$1:/home/sirish.aditya/mem_11-19.csv /Users/sirish.aditya/workSpace/cpustats_srm/$1
scp sirish.aditya@$1:/home/sirish.aditya/cpu_11-19.csv /Users/sirish.aditya/workSpace/cpustats_srm/$1
```

And run it as you mentioned above:

`ssh sirish.aditya@remote_machine 'bash -s' < memory.sh remote_machine`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
set -x

ssh $1 <<'EOT'

cd /var/log/sysstat/

for (( i = 11; i <= 19; i++ ))

do

 sar -f $i >> /home/sirish.aditya/cpu_11-19.csv

 sar -f $i -r >> /home/sirish.aditya/mem_11-19.csv

done
EOT

mkdir /Users/sirish.aditya/workSpace/cpustats_srm/$1

scp sirish.aditya@$1:/home/sirish.aditya/mem_11-19.csv /Users/sirish.aditya/workSpace/cpustats_srm/$1

scp sirish.aditya@$1:/home/sirish.aditya/cpu_11-19.csv /Users/sirish
```

Uses a [here doc](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) to send the commands you are trying to run remotely.

Comment: I'm getting an authentication error for both these solutions. Let me try once more and get back. Thanks for the quick response! @avihoo-mamka +julian